# Django: Is it possible to trigger shell command in the client?

Tags: django, shell

I wanted to do a `iwlist scanning` on the client but I want this to happen only when the client clicks on the button in a webpage. Server uses Django. Is this possible?

I know this could cause some security concerns but that is not my focus right now. I'm trying to create a location fingerprinting-based web app.

Comment: Are you trying to run the script on the client or the server?

Comment: At the client. I wanted to find out the access points that the client's machine can detect.

Comment: So the point of this application is just to figure out the location of the user? You'll have to implement the APIs for each client you want to support. From FFX, Safari, Chrome, iPhone, Android, etc. geo-locating the IP address is the only other real way, that I can think of.

Comment: I wanted to make use of location fingerprinting without making use of special services other than a browser. As per previous research, it is possible to determine the indoor location of a user using the detected signal strengths of different access points in the area.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that, under some browsers, it's possible for file://-based tools like TiddlyWiki to launch applications by referencing them with file://, but I don't know if you can do it with an argument and, as I remember, modern browsers only let you link to file:// from a page that's already loaded via file:// to explicitly prevent that kind of exploit.

In theory, it can be used in ways similar to what made ActiveX such a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers are all designed to expressly prohibit the kind of action you are trying to perform--namely running some arbitrary binary on the client machine. There is no way to accomplish that short of taking advantage of some security hole.

If you write a custom Chrome Extension or Firefox addon and get the user to download and install it, then *maybe* you can do something like that, but even extensions/addons are kept in a very tightly controlled sandbox by the browser to keep the client machine safe.

Comment: So I guess making the app a runnable application in the client is the only solution?

Comment: @Carlo Yes, basically you're not going to be able access any client-side functionality outside of the browser with just a simple webpage.